# Android-Week-View loading events per week asynchronously

Tags: java, android, android-layout

First off, I'm using the library https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

I have an API returning data for one week at a time.

For example GET /stuff/{current_week_number}

Then a scroll listener set up that checks if the week has changed, and will then load

GET /stuff/{new_week_number}

The problem is that all events will be in the current week position as duplicates. I know the library wants events on a per month basis, is it the problem?

Been debugging this for a day now, help would be greatly appreciated.

Function for creating the event:

```
private WeekViewEvent createNew(JSONObject json, int week) {
        String eventTitle = "";
        String colorString = "#999";
        String startTimeString = "";
        String endTimeString = "";
        int dayOfWeek = 0;

        try {
            eventTitle = json.getString("text").replaceAll("\n", " ");
            colorString = json.getString("color");
            startTimeString = json.getString("startTime");
            endTimeString = json.getString("endTime");
            dayOfWeek = json.getInt("day");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursFromString(startTimeString));
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesFromString(startTimeString));
        startTime.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
        startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

        Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursFromString(endTimeString));
        endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesFromString(endTimeString));

        WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(mGlobalCounter, eventTitle, startTimeString + " - " + endTimeString, startTime, endTime);
        event.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorString));

        if (event.getColor() == Color.WHITE) {
            event.setColor(R.color.event_color_01);
        }
        return event;
    }
```

Month change listener + helper method (from example)

```
private boolean eventMatches(WeekViewEvent event, int year, int month) {
        return (event.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR) == year && event.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH) == month - 1) || (event.getEndTime().get(Calendar.YEAR) == year && event.getEndTime().get(Calendar.MONTH) == month - 1);
    }

MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener mMonthChangeListener = new MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        // Populate the week view with some events.
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<>(); //getEvents(newYear, newMonth);


            for (WeekViewEvent event : mNewEvents) {
                if (eventMatches(event, newYear, newMonth)) {
                    events.add(event);
                }
            }

            mFetchedWeeks.add(Integer.valueOf(mWeek));

        return events;
    }
};
```

And here's the JSON-response from the API
https://gist.github.com/jonathanort/668de267966e3b673fffe23dfbdfb90b

Also, my modified version of WeekView.java
https://gist.github.com/jonathanort/472d86355dcdbc338f13373a838f548a

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the line

```
    startTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

before

```
  startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
```

Apparently it will not set the day otherwise